# Does the grappling dire tiger get to rake on an Attack of Opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, opportunity-attack, grapple

[Dire Tiger](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/felines/cat-great/tiger/dire-tiger/) [pounces](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Pounce-Ex-) a character (bite claw claw rake rake) and successfully grabs. (More unnecessary context in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47316951#47316951).)

On his turn the character pulls out a potion of gaseous form from a handy haversack (i.e. no AoO) and drinks it (which provokes!).

Now does the tiger get an attack as usual, or three including two from (another) [rake](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Rake-Ex-)?

Answer (score 5):

### Normally the tiger would get one AoO on the character; however, the tiger can't make AoO at all while grappling.

From [grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) rules:

> [..] If successful, both you and the target gain the grappled condition. If you successfully grapple a creature that is not adjacent to you, move that creature to an adjacent open space (if no space is available, your grapple fails). Although **both creatures have the grappled condition**, you can, as the creature that initiated the grapple, release the grapple as a free action, removing the condition from both you and the target. [...]

And the [grappled](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled) condition states:

> Grappled creatures **cannot make** attacks of opportunity.

So no AoO in this case. The only way the tiger can make AoO and grappling the character is using this special rule of the [Grab](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Grab-Ex-) ability to prevent itself from taking the grappled condition:

> [...] The creature has the option to conduct the grapple normally, or simply use the part of its body it used in the grab to hold the opponent. If it chooses to do the latter, it **takes a –20 penalty on its CMB check to make and maintain the grapple, but does not gain the grappled condition itself.**

---

To be more specific and clarify Hey I Can Chan's comment the rake ability gives you 2 free extra attacks...but they are still 2 attacks. You have only **one** AoO so you can use only **one** of your attacks. Before the grapple you had only 3 attacks; now you have 5 against the grappled target but, since this is an AoO, you must choose only **one** of this five to make the AoO.

> Making an Attack of Opportunity
>
> An attack of opportunity is a **single melee attack**, and most characters can only make one per round. You don’t have to make an attack of opportunity if you don’t want to. You make your attack of opportunity at your normal attack bonus, even if you’ve already attacked in the round.

(*Emphasis added to quotes*)

Comment: Oh so the tiger has the option to grab on tightly (no AoO) or not (no grappled condition for him) - good catch on the -20 --- so maybe getting away is an option --- would the character know if he's grappled tightly or not?

Comment: Assuming you are not threatened by other than the grappler and the grappler has the grappled condition (so he is not taking -20 at cmb) yes, you can drink a potion safely.
@Julix yes, i think is legit that a character knows a visible condition like grappled or entangled.

Comment: While this does a fine job of pointing out one of the question's assumptions, it doesn't go back to answer the question. What if the tiger *is* taking the -20? Then "does the tiger get an attack as usual or three including two from (another) rake?" (Note that the question should make this the *second* round the tiger has the creature grappled as per the special ability rake— "A monster with the rake ability must begin its turn already grappling to use its rake")

Comment: Note the tiger also gets to use rake on pounce, so that particular limitation doesn't seem to apply to tigers, right?

Comment: @Julix Yes that limitation apply to tigers too ofcourse. Pounce is a specific rule that alters the general rule. If you have pounce and rake you can rake if you are pouncing.

Comment: I see your point - so you're saying after you're done pouncing you have to wait until you're starting a turn with the enemy grappled ( tiger doesn't have to be in grappled condition to rake, right? - as long as the enemy is... ) 

So that means at least right after pounce, even if it chooses to hold down at -20 it would get only a bite AoO...

Comment: @Julix To explain the full iteration of grapple checks is hard here in comments, if you know how to chat send me a message. Anyway, in few words, yes the need to wait the start of her next turn after the turn where she pounced and yes if she has the grappled condition or not doesn't matter.

Comment: Cheers, I think I got it now.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I cleaned up a couple parts of your answer and added links to the rules you mentioned. If you don't like it, feel free to roll the edit back or re-edit it as you see fit. Great answer though!

Comment: @Ifusaso Thank you! And sorry for some mistakes, i'm not a native english speaker.